# Dealing with ambiguous occurrence in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module

I'm importing both `Data.Text` and `Data.List` and their respective `find` functions collapse.

```hs
import Data.Text
import Data.List

my_list = [4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6]
find (\a -> a == 5) my_list
```

The above code leads to the following error

```
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘find’
    It could refer to
       either ‘Data.Text.find’, imported from ‘Data.Text’
           or ‘Data.List.find’,
              imported from ‘Data.List’
              (and originally defined in ‘Data.Foldable’)
```

Is the only solution to use `Data.List.find (\a -> a == 5) my_list` here, or qualified imports?

What strikes me is that

```hs
Data.List.find (\a -> a == 5) my_list
--> Just 5

Data.Text.find (\a -> a == 5) my_list
--> error: Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
```

From the `find` function signatures, the compiler is apparently able to understand that `Data.Text.find` doesn't work with `[Integer]`. Can't he use this information to decide on which instance of `find` to use and, in this case, automatically use `find` from `Data.List` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the only solution to use `Data.List.find (\a -> a == 5) my_list` here, or qualified imports?

As far as I know, yes, there are no other solutions.

The compiler won't try to type-check both options and use the one which makes your code compile. In the most general case, that could lead to an exponential blow-up. Consider, e.g.,

```
foo a1 a2 .... aN
```

where each one of `a1` .. `aN` are imported from two distinct modules. Trying which combination type-checks would in principle require to test 2^N combinations.

Further, there's always the chance that the programmer meant to use an identifier from a module, but they made a mistake and the code does not type-check. In this case, the same identifier from the other module might instead type-check, making the code compile but producing the wrong result. (This is a rather contrived example, I know.)

---

Note that, if in your importing module you only need to use one of the two `find`s you can hide the other:

```
import Data.Text hiding (find)
import Data.List
```

Alternatively, you can provide explicit disjoint import lists:

```
import Data.Text (pack)
import Data.List (find, zip)
```

If you need both `find`s, you can provide a shorter name for the module

```
import Data.Text as T
import Data.List as L
```

as then disambiguate using `L.find`. You won't need the shorter module name except for the doubly imported identifiers. If you use `import qualified` instead you will need to specify the module name for all imported identifiers.

Comment: just to clarify, does it mean that there is no such thing as multiple dispatch in Haskell? [like in Julia for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Julia), where you can define the same function name multiple times but with different argument types, and the compiler will do the job? or am I misunderstanding something

Comment: @Jivan Not in that way. You can achieve multiple dispatch using typeclasses. E.g. `show True` and `show (42 :: Int)` both work, and have separate implementations, leaving the compiler to choose the right one depending on the type (instance resolution). The two implementations could even be written in distinct modules. One has to ask for that declaring a class and defining instances: just using the same name in two modules is not enough.

Comment: "As far as I know, yes, there are no other solutions." - that's not really true, unless you need to use both functions at different places in your module. If you only need one, you can hide the other in the import statement - or even better imo, use explicit import lists rather than importing everything from a module.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Right, I somehow took that for granted given the OP examples, but perhaps I was wrong with that.